# Jenkins CI/CD setup for a microservices system

Tags: jenkins, devops

I have a system with dozens of microservices, all build and released the same way - each is in a docker container, and deployed in a Kubernetes cluster.

There are multiple clusters (Dev1, dev2, QA ... Prod)

We are using Jenkins to deploy each microservice. Each microservice has its own pipeline and this pipelines is duplicated for each environment, like so:

DEV1 *(view)*

- dev1_microserviceA  *(job / pipline)*
- dev1_microserviceB
- ...
- dev1_microserviceX

DEV2

- dev1_microserviceA
- dev1_microserviceB
- ...
- dev1_microserviceX

...

PROD

- dev1_microserviceA
- dev1_microserviceB
- ...
- dev1_microserviceX

each of those pipelines is almost identical, differences are really just a matter of parameters like environment, name of the microservice, name of git repo.

Some common code is in libraries that each pipeline uses. Is this the proper / typical setup and most refactored setup? I'd like to avoid having to create a pipeline for each microservice and for each envionment but not sure what are my further refactoring options. I am new to Jenkins & devops.

I've looked into parametrized pipelines but I do not want to have to enter a parameter each time I need to build, and I also need to be able to chain builds, and see the results of all builds at a glance, in each environment.

Comment: Setting up CI/CD services is *largely* opinionated and largely depends on what you and your team feel most comfortable with doing.  We're not going to be able to definitively answer this for you.

Comment: @Makoto, I know. Is it really detrimental to the stackoverflow to have a number of suggestions to a common problem like this?

Comment: @Makoto can you suggest a different place where such a question / call for recommendations can be made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Declarative Pipelines where you can define your logic in a local `Jenkinsfile` in your repositories.

Using Jenkins, you can have a "master" `Jenkinsfile` and/or project that you can inherit by invoking the upstream project. This will allow you to effectively share your instructions and reduce duplication.

What is typically never covered when it comes to CI/CD is the "management" of deployments. Since most CI/CD services are stateless it has no notion of applications deployed.

GitLab has come a long way with this but Jenkins is far behind.

At the end of the day you will have to either create a separate project for each repository/purpose due to how Jenkins works OR (recommended) have a "master" project that let's you pass in things like project name, git repo url, specific application variables and values and so on.